# Manipulating records in a File

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a requirement in Dataframes. I have a complex file with 4 types (A, B, C, D) of records. The record type is determined by the **first** character of each record in the file. We have to deal with only record types A & B (C & D are ignored).
The characters 8 thru 13 of the A record is the pointer to its corresponding B record in the file. Record B would contain this id in positions 14 thru 19.
The requirement is to read the file and update record B by extracting the value of positions 14 thru 25 from its corresponding record A and update the string '&1' in record B.

```
A345621236745HAWAII 
B245639GHIWRT236745 &i HI
C8768134484MN 09239
D677188HD78SFI89012
```

Hence, the final output will be:

```
A345621236745HAWAII
B245639GHIWRT236745 HAWAII HI
C8768134484MN 09239
D677188HD78SFI89012
```

As could be seen above the key field in A (positions 8-13) is '236745' is matched with its record B (positions 14-19. And, in record A, 14-25 positions is 'HAWAII' which is updated in record B by replacing the string '&i' in record B. Records C and D are ignored.

Can anyone please help to write this logic in PySpark Dataframes.
Thanks.